# Animation/transition between data plots

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram, visualization, data-visualization

I'll need to make a fancy presentation of my data and I'm looking for some advice on data visualisation (transition between plots).

I have data from multiple subjects, each of which pressed a key as they were listening to a piece of music. The raw data (subject-level keypresses), plotted in Matlab 2016a, looks like this, where each line is one subject, and each keypress is one dot (colour-coding reflects various conditions in the music):
[image]

This histogram (also made in Matlab) then counts the keypresses inside 1s-wide time bins:
[image]

I'd like to first show the raw data, then the histogram, but with an animation in between, to show how the raw data makes up the histogram . Something like the dots "falling" down and accummulating into peaks&valleys (the histogram's shorter/taller bins).

Matlab almost certainly cannot do this, and neither can Powerpoint of course, since it does not have access to the data itself but only to the plot image.

Can anyone recommend any Windows software that can - preferably open-source?

Comment: Just a side note which has nothing to do with your question: I have no idea how familiar your audience is with your experiment and data acquisition, however, from my perspective, a naive person, I have no idea what I should see in both figures. I would rather describe them as "noise" as there is so much information which is not self explanatory. I understand that you want to show what you have done and so on ... but as I was thought ... just show the relevant things which you dont have to explain long but which clearly underlay what you say.

Comment: You are correct that Matlab only plots images. As far as I know, in order to create an animation, you have to code each frame of the animation, i.e. calculating the position of each dot and plotting the dots using Matlab. You will also need a short pause in between each frame, `pause(1/30)` should do for a 30fps animation.